# How does program know to continue to new string?

Tags: c++

When i use `while(cin >> word) { cout << word }` program shows all the word i write one by one. But i cant understand why. When we use ints we write something like i++ to end the loop. My question is how does the program knows to write the next word and not the first word over and over again?

Comment: If you don't know what a `while` loop does, you should probably read an introductory book on C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cin >> word` does two separate things; it reads a word from the input (changing the state of `cin`) and then tells you whether it succeeded (so the loop knows when to terminate). Next time round the loop `cin` knows what you've already read and moves on to the next thing.

So it's a function with side-effects; as well as returning a result it also alters the state of the system. There are two  views of this - it's a very bad idea that makes understanding code hard, and it's very useful for writing simple but powerful code. Both are true to some extent.

Comment: What would be the easy to read (but still correct) alternative in this case?

Comment: I don't see a good alternative here - we'd need to make it a lot more complex. But then iostreans, and perhaps C++ in general, tends to embrace side-effects. Here I think it's harmless; it can cause problems in more complex cases.

Comment: @sepp, this is pretty easy to read. `while( condition )` should be amongst every programmer's known constructs. If you're not used to the idiom `while (stream >> variable)` now's a good time to get used to it, as it is very concise and robust .

Comment: One of the most common mistakes posted on SO under C and C++ tags is failure to check whether an input operation succeeded or not.

Answer (score 0):

Because the condition `cin >> word` is executed in each iteration of the loop. Thus before the cout statement becomes executed, the cin statement is executed, setting `word` to the current entered string.